# How to generate multi aar with multi library module in one task?

Tags: android, gradle, aar

There is an android project base on gradle,whick has one application module an two library moudle.

```
MyApplication
├── app
├── libA
└── libB
```

The app moudle implementation libA, and libA implementation libB
The build.gradle file is just like this.
app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    flavorDimensions "test"
    productFlavors {
                      flavor1{}
                      flavor2{}
                   }
   dependencies {
                    implementation project(':libA')
                }
}
```

libA

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    flavorDimensions "test"
    productFlavors {
                      flavor1{}
                      flavor2{}
                   }
   dependencies {
                    implementation project(':libB')
                }
}
```

libB

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
}
```

When I run the project's gradle task assembleFlavor1Release, I got the output just like this,

```
MyApplication
├── app
│   └── output
│       └── app-flavor1-release.apk
├── libA
│   └── output
│       └── libA-flavor1-release.aar
└── libB
    └── output
```

There is no libB's output aar under the output dir.
For some reason, I can't add flavor in libB.
Is there any way to generate two aar for libA and libB at the same time?

Comment: Can you post the complete build config for ´libB´?

Comment: libB is a simple module that not have flavors. I upload the question's demo on github at https://github.com/olbb/Que62906594. You can get it there if you want.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change :

```
implementation project(':libA')
implementation project(':libB')
```

into

```
api  project(':libA')
api  project(':libB')
```